# Why do inline/IRRE records get sys_language_uid=0?

Tags: internationalization, typo3, typo3-9.x

When creating a `tt_content` record in `sys_language_uid = 2` (no translation/`l10n_parent = 0`) in backend and inserting fields in a `type => 'inline'` column `tx_foo_slider_slides` (definition below), the newly created records in `tx_foo_domain_model_slide` are created with `sys_language_uid = 0`. Adding an image to the slide's image field creates a `sys_file_reference` with `sys_language_uid = 2`. **Is this correct? If not, how do I change this?** I would expected to have all records (`tt_content`, `tx_foo_slider_slides`, `sys_file_reference`) created with `sys_language_uid = 2`. It seems that records created before the update do have `sys_language_uid` set to 2, but I am not sure what has changed between 8 and 9: is it a core change? Or my site/language configuration? `sys_language_uid` had a default of 0 in TCA, but removing that and creating additional records did not show any different behaviour.

When trying to load records through an ExtBase repository where I seemingly have to use `setRespectSysLanguage(false)`:

- I do get no results with `setLanguageOverlayMode(false)`
- I do get results with `setLanguageOverlayMode(true)`, but the image field is `NULL`.

  - ... but if I also manually change the `tx_foo_domain_model_slide.sys_language_uid` to 2 it looks fine in BE and FE/ExtBase (`image` is a working `FileReference`)

**What could be going wrong? What might need to be changed? I think creating records in non-default languages is a supported case?** For me, the root cause seems to be that records are created with the wrong language set.

My configuration:

- TYPO3 9.5.5 (updated from 8)
- `config.tx_extbase.features.consistentTranslationOverlayHandling = 1` (but tested `0`, too)
- `config.sys_language_overlay = 0` (I don't think `1` or `hideNonTranslated` changed any behaviour)
- Sites (and multi-site). This specific site comes with two languages:

  - Language 1, German (`languageId: '0'`) is disabled.
  - Language 2, English (`languageId: '2'`) is enabled; `fallbackType: strict`
- A custom table `tx_foo_domain_model_slide` including language fields and an `image` column:

```
'image' => [
  'label' => $ll.'tx_foo_domain_model_slide.image',
  'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
    'image',
    [
      'appearance' => [
        'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => 'LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:images.addFileReference',
      ],
      'overrideChildTca' => [
        // types ...
      ],
      'minitems' => 1,
      'maxitems' => 1,
    ],
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext'] .',m4v,mp4v,mp4'
  ),
],
```

- A column `tx_foo_slider_slides` in `tt_content`:

```
[
  'label' => $ll . 'slider.slides',
  'config' => [
     'type' => 'inline',
     'appearance' => [
       'collapseAll' => true,
       'expandSingle' => true,
     ],
     'foreign_field' => 'slider',
     'foreign_sortby' => 'sorting',
     'foreign_table' => 'tx_foo_domain_model_slide',
     'maxitems' => 100,
     'minitems' => 0,
   ],
 ],
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in this case is, that `tx_foo_domain_model_slide.sys_language_uid` is defined as:

```
'sys_language_uid' => [
  'config' => [
    'type' => 'passthrough',
    'default' => '',
  ],
],
```

According to the [TCA docs](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Type/Passthrough.html):

> - FormEngine does not render anything for passthrough types by default. But it can be combined with a custom renderType to make it render something. A user type is better suited for such use cases, though.
> - Type passthrough field values are usually also not rendered at other places in the backend.

This leads to `sys_language_uid` not being set (and staying at 0). So, `sys_language_uid` has to be defined as `'type` => 'select'` or similar. To hide it, one can put it in a [hidden palette](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Palettes/Index.html#ishiddenpalette), as described [here](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/76048?fbclid=IwAR36F-BIY8F11AwKUL4Q_ngOzahjn_uvmFPhg6GQiKDMeXelDp2svHLfAoE#note-22).